# long double going to infinity

Tags: c++11, largenumber

I am calculating very large numbers and I know that doubles have a way of dealing with them, representing them as the first digits of the number and an error (+- 10^power).

```
        long double numerator = (1103L + 26390L * n);
        long double denominator = pow(396L, 4L * n);
        for (size_t j = 1; j <= 4 * n; j++)
        {
            numerator *= j;
        }
        for (size_t j = 1; j <= n; j++)
        {
            denominator *= pow(j, 4);
        }

        currentSum+= numerator / denominator;
```

When n is about 40 I get an error of about 10^260 and then it starts returning infinity (inf). (For example if n=37, then the numerator value becomes 2.49889e+264) If the error power of 10 exceeds 300 it returns infinity. Shouldn't it return values for the power of 10 until these values exceed the size of a "long" type, since the numbers are of type long double?

Comment: What do you mean by "*until these values exceed the size of a `long` type*"? If `long` is 8 bytes on your machine, the maximum value it can hold is roughly 1.8^19. That is far less than the `long double` capacity. Please clarify.

Comment: _e_ does not stand for error.  It stands for exponent.

Comment: OK lets say that the long type is 4 bytes. -2,147,483,648 to 2,147,483,647. That means that the double should be max  2,147,483,647e+2,147,483,648, not 2,147,483,647e+300. Get it?

Comment: [On a typical, IEEE-compatible implementation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format), `double` is 64 bits (8 bytes) large. Of those, 52 bits represent the mantissa, 11 bits the exponent and one sign bit. Therefore, the largest representable value is on the order of `2^1024` or `10^308`. You seem to assume 32/32 split between mantissa and exponent - that's not how it's usually done.